# Retrieve files from FTP using spring integration FtpOutboundGateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to retrieve the `ls` information from a ftp side using: `org.springframework.integration.ftp.gateway.ftpoutboundgateway`.

From the javadoc i understand we can execute a command like ls, mget to retrieve the information via the `FtpoOutboundGateway`.

**My question is how to do this?**

I have setup a ftpSessionFactory. I have tested this session with FtpRemoteFileTemplate and can successfully retrieve a file (via get() ).

But i am lost how to do this via the gateway. 
I want to do this via coding, not using xml files for configuration.

So what i do is create a gateway:
 new FtpOutboundGateway(defaultFtpSessionFactory, "ls -R", null);

what will be the next step to execute the command?  (do the ls retrieval from the ftp side)

I was expecting that this would actually fire and could retrieve the result, but this is totally unclear to me.

I also cannot find a coding example (just xml configurations) or get this from the javadoc/integration documentation how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The `FtpOutboundGateway` is an EIP component which should be configured as a bean in the Integration flow scenario.

With that you should send a `Message` for an endpoint `inputChannel`, the `FtpOutboundGateway` performs a command for you and reply with a particular `Message` in to its `outputChannel`.

All that info you can find in the Spring Integration [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/), especially [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips), if your goal to achieve "xmlless" configuration.

We don't have an `FtpOutboundGateway` Java Config sample, but you can find something in the Spring Integration Java DSL [test-cases](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/ftp/FtpTests.java):

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler ftpOutboundGateway() {
    return Ftp.outboundGateway(this.ftpSessionFactory,
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "payload")
            .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
            .regexFileNameFilter("(subFtpSource|.*1.txt)")
            .localDirectoryExpression("@ftpServer.targetLocalDirectoryName + #remoteDirectory")
            .localFilenameExpression("#remoteFileName.replaceFirst('ftpSource', 'localTarget')")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpMGetFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("ftpMgetInputChannel")
            .handle(ftpOutboundGateway())
            .channel(remoteFileOutputChannel())
            .get();
}
```

Also see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1860

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information. I used your info to come up with a solution that fits my needs. I really wanted to use the abstraction of the commands given by the gateway, not the full integration way. Thanks again for the info.

My solution is as follows, to be able to use the gateways functionality without using the full integration stack. I posted it here, maybe some other persons can make use of it. This example is only working on the ls command, but can work for all commands given by the gateway easily.

```
class FtpGateway {

@Autowired
private DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory;

private List<String> ftpFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

class ProcessCommandReturn extends AbstractMessageChannel {

    @Override
    protected boolean doSend(Message<?> message, long timeout) {
        ftpFiles.clear();
        ArrayList<FileInfo> fileNames = (ArrayList<FileInfo>) message.getPayload();
        for (FileInfo filename : fileNames) {
            ftpFiles.add(filename.getFilename());
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public List<String> getFileListFromFTP() throws IOException {

    FtpOutboundGateway gw = new FtpOutboundGateway(defaultFtpSessionFactory, "ls", "'last*.zip'");
    // set return processing 
    MessageChannel ochannel = new ProcessCommandReturn();
    e.setOutputChannel(ochannel);
    // make the gateway do it's work
    gw.handleMessage(new GenericMessage(""));
    return ftpFiles;
}
}
```